# Cypress can't find data-testid

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I am new to end to end testing and using Cypress for the first time . I have an application, made with Nextjs & Material UI in which I want to write a test for a profile page. I have the following test to check whether username is shown or not:

```
it("Username",()=>{
        cy.wait(10000)
        cy.get('[data-testid="username"]',{withinSubject:null}).should('exit'); // getting error on this command.
        cy.contains('@').should('exit')
      })
```

But Cypress is not able to find the `data-testid="username"` even I have set the `data-testid="username"` to the component which will show the username:

```
{loading ? (
                <Skeleton variant="text" width={100} animation="wave" />
              ) : (
                <span className="text-sm text-grey-normal" data-testid="username">
                  @{userInfo?.get("spectUsername")}
                </span>
              )}
```

I have also tried the method included in this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14566) to solve the problem but this also don't work for me. I have searched a lot about this issue but can't find a working solution . What I am doing wrong ? How to make it work ? Is there any module I am forgetting to import to make this working ?

Comment: Sounds like your test run before DOM element render. You must first wait `loading` and then call `cy.get('[data-testid="username"]'`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Even the DOM has rendered the element it still failing . I have also tested with 20 sec wait .

Comment: Oh, man, i think you have a typo. Check `.should('exit');` and use `.should('exist');`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets . Thanks alot man!! I single typo spoiled my day

Comment: Make sure to remove the explicit wait. Also, the `{withinSubject:null}` is redundant since it is a default value already. Also, if the component is visible on the browser, you should change `exist` to `be.visible`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **exist** in should method as below

```
cy.get('[data-testid="username"]',{withinSubject:null}).should('exist');
```

Else you can use  length greater than function to know if username entered or not.

```
cy.get('[data-testid="username"]').should(($lis) => {              
 expect($lis).to.have.length.greaterThan(0);
});
```